# Equation with a division in exponent

Tags: exponentiation

I have an equation: 10,9 * 2^(x/1,5) = 1000 and want to calculate the value of x.

x being in the exponent is my problem. How can I get to something like: x = ...

Comment: Hint: Can you isolate the exponent on the LHS and then take logs of both sides?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thx I know what to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the comma to denote the decimal so I'll use the same notation.

$$2^{x/1,5}=\frac{1000}{10,9}=\alpha\iff x=1,5\times\frac{\alpha}{\log2}$$